# An "_=13 digits" will be added to js files in Struts 2 jQuery plugin project

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

In a Struts 2 jQuery plugin project, consider a simple JSP page which includes a JS file in it

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/sample.js"></script>
```

When you look at at actual requested URL ( for example by using Firefox firebug) you see that the an underline with a 13 digit is added to the end of URL:

```
localhost:8080/js/sample.js?_=1402322518885
```

when you refresh the page it will look like

```
localhost:8080/js/sample.js?_=1402322518886
localhost:8080/js/sample.js?_=1402322518887
localhost:8080/js/sample.js?_=1402322518888
```

You can see this by visiting http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action. Open firebug network control then Go to `widgets/spinner` menu and you can see that the `globalize.js` will be called something like `globalize.js?_=1402323154341`

This prevent the JS to be cached on client. Do you know what is this and how can we prevent it?! 
I found that this will not apply to all JS files, as far as I found if your Ajax loaded content has an JS function in it, it will be called with underline plus number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 jQuery plugin uses jQuery and this feature is related to not caching pages in jQuery. The plugin is configurable to change this feature via attribute `ajaxcache` of the [`head`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag) tag. From the docs

```
Name        ajaxcache       
Required    false       
Default     false       
Evaluated   false       
Type        Boolean     
Description If set to false it will force the pages that you request to not be 
            cached by the browser.
```

Using the code below in the `index.jsp` will change not caching default

```
<s:if test="%{theme == 'showcase' || theme == null}">
    <sj:head debug="true" compressed="true" jquerytheme="showcase" customBasepath="themes" loadFromGoogle="%{google}" ajaxhistory="%{ajaxhistory}" defaultIndicator="myDefaultIndicator" defaultLoadingText="Please wait ..." ajaxcache="true"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <sj:head debug="true" compressed="true" jquerytheme="%{theme}" loadFromGoogle="%{google}" ajaxhistory="%{ajaxhistory}" defaultIndicator="myDefaultIndicator" defaultLoadingText="Please wait ..." ajaxcache="true"/>
</s:else>
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know it applies to which ajax request types 'script' , 'jsonp' ...

Comment: The plugin docs is not well documented on this case, but I think you can find this on jQuery site.

Comment: One note about jQuery, I thought it loads scripts with `$.getScript()` and this setting is used by the plugin. See how it [caches the requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests).

Answer (score 1):

That is a Unix Timestamp ([representing today at 16:01 GMT+2](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/)).

It is added by the underlying `jQuery.ajax` (not by `Struts2-jQuery-plugin`) to prevent the browser from caching the files (to deal with IE caching, I guess), either when :

1. you've set `cache: false;` or
2. the dataType is of type **script** (as in your case) or **jsonp**.

From [the official doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **cache** (default: `true`, `false` for `dataType 'script'` and `'jsonp'`)
>
> Type: *Boolean*
>
> If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. **Note:** Setting `cache` to `false` will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending `"_={timestamp}"` to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Solution: load your file through jQuery ajax forcing `cache: true`, or load it without using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, By your comments, I found that when the jsp file contains an js file and the jsp file is loaded with ajax, then the included js file will also be loaded via ajax too. The struts2 jquery plugin make the ajax call itself. I tried the $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false  }); but it is still there! any comments ?!

Comment: yes, you need to do `cache: true` ! :)  `cache : false` is the default for script and jsonp ;)

Comment: a big typo mistake :) I tried `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});` but it did not worked!